# Update custom field on page specific to logged in user

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have a page that displays data specific to the user who has logged in--charts, etc.  That works great.

I have added a few custom fields on that page where I insert values using update_post_meta().

The problem: How do I use update_post_meta() or other function(s), to only update the field with the data specific to the user who is viewing that page?

Right now, the way I have written the code, MY data is showing and every user who would view the page would see my data and not theirs.

Any directions/hints would be most appreciated.

Quint

Comment: to know the current user identifier, you can use that : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

Comment: @mmm, are you saying that I employ a conditional that checks/verifies the user id and then output accordingly?  I'm a little fuzzy on how the database stores this dynamic user data.  If I have 10,000 users, then each user has their own record where that custom field data is recorded and can then be viewed on that page if they are logged in?

Comment: I have misgivings about how this will scale with hundreds of users. If you want to store user specific things, post meta is not the place for it, that's why we have user meta. But since you've posted no code, it's difficult to make a suggestion

Comment: @TomJNowell, thanks for the suggestion.  I am now storing the data in the user meta table.